# Part of my site toggles display property when I reach the bottom of the page. What could be causing this?

Tags: wordpress

http://69.16.227.220/~amltowin/

If you scroll to the bottom of this page, the side-menu toggles display when you reach the bottom of the page. I can't figure out what is causing it during the run-time. How can I fix this?

Built using wordpress, and beaver builder

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. For me the side-menu keeps open when I scroll to the bottom of the page.

Try to clean your browser cache if you've been modifying files.